# start and stop timer of one view from another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

in my app there are two views. view1 has a function testing

```
  -(void) testing
  {
       NSLog(@"Testing : %d", (++x));
  }
```

and a timer

```
  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self   selector:@selector(testing) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

what i want, is to stop and run this timer from view2. How to do that ?

Comment: create `timerV2` `ivar` in `view2` then pass `timer` to `view2`

Comment: can you please write the code because i am new to Objectice C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define Timer in AppDelegate,

```
@interface TimerDemoAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
NSTimer *timer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;

@end
```

And use timer in your both view by creating TimerDemoAppDelegate object
in your view .h file

```
@interface View1 : UIViewController
{
TimerDemoAppDelegate *appDelegate;
}
```

in your view .m file

```
appDelegate=(TimerDemoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

now use timer as appDelegate.timer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `timer2` to your `View2` class

```
@interface View2 : UIView{
    NSTimer *timer2;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSTimer *timer2;
@end


@implementation View2
@synthesize timer2;
@end
```

and do like this

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self   selector:@selector(testing) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
view2.timer2 = timer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSNotificationCenter` you can call methods from another view without creating any objects.

In your `viewDidLoad`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(button:) 
                                             name:@"Next"
                                           object:nil];

-(void)button:(NSNotification *) notification
{
 // write a code of timer here.....
}


//call this following from another view

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 postNotificationName:@"Next" 
 object:self];
```

Enjoy with this code....